# How to calculate a geometric mean based on cell values?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, shinydashboard, rhandsontable

There are the `table 1` and `table 2` as shown in the script below. I have the following task:
(1) The 1st row of the `table 2` should represent a geometric mean of the 1st and 3rd rows of the `table 1`;
(2) The 2nd row of the `table 2` = a geometric mean of the 2nd and 4th rows of the `table 1`.

I would be grateful if someone can help me.

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(rhandsontable)
    library(data.table)
    library(dplyr)

    "df1" <- data.table(column1 = as.numeric(c(3,8,3,8)))
    "df2" <- data.table(column2 = as.numeric(c(0,0)))

   ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Geometric Mean Calculation"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        menuItem("Calculation", tabName = "calculation",
                               menuSubItem("Gmean", tabName = "table1"))),
      dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
          tabItem(
        tabName = "table1",
            column(
              "table 1",
          width=6,
              rHandsontableOutput("Table1")
            ),
            column(
              "table 2",
          width=6,
              rHandsontableOutput("Table2")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )

   server = function(input, output) {

    data <- reactiveValues()

    observe({input$recalc
            data$`DF1`<- as.data.frame(`df1`)
            data$`DF2`<- as.data.frame(`df2`)
    })
    observe({if(!is.null(input$Table1))
        data$`DF1` <- hot_to_r(input$Table1)
    })
    observe({if(!is.null(input$Table2))
        data$`DF2` <- hot_to_r(input$Table2)
    })

    geometric_mean1<- reactive({with(data$`DF1`, 
                              (column1[1]*column1[3])**(1/2))})
    
    observe({
        if(!is.null(geometric_mean1())){
        data$`DF2`$column2[1] <- geometric_mean1()[[1]]}
    })

    geometric_mean2<- reactive({with(data$`DF1`, 
                               (column1[2]*column1[4])**(1/2))})
    
    observe({
        if(!is.null(geometric_mean2())){
        data$`DF2`$column2[2] <- geometric_mean2()[[1]]}
    })

    output$Table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(data$`DF1`)
    })
    output$Table2 <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(data$`DF2`)
    })

    }
   
   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What have you tired?  What's not working?  Are you getting error messages?  As present your question is basically just a work prompt and Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: I know how to find geometric mean for all values of one vector but i cannot figure out how to calculate the mean of selected cells of a column instead of doing it for the whole vector as such. I cheked for such `rhandsontable` functions as hot_cell, hot_row, hot_table, and hot_rows but none of them have an argument to select specific cells of the vector.

Comment: According to CRAN website R Programming Language has got more than 17K packages. Hence, it would be helpful at least to direct me whether there is any package with certain functions approriate for use in my case.

Comment: As per concept, I have tried following ways of calculating geometric mean dealing only with the whole vector or values of two different variables, althought they do not give a solution to what i want:

Comment: SAMPLE script 1:


library(rhandsontable)

data <- data.frame(
  Col1= c(1, 2, 3),
  Col2= c(4, 5, 6)
)

result <- apply(data, 1, function(row) {
  sqrt(row[1] * row[2])
})

result

Comment: SAMPLE script 2:

library(rhandsontable)

data <- data.frame(
  col1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  col2 = c(4, 5, 6)
)

result <- apply(data, 2, function(x) prod(x)^(1/length(x)))

result

Comment: SAMPLE script 3:

library(rhandsontable)

data <- data.frame(Column = c(10, 20))

result <- sqrt(prod(data$Column))

result

Comment: SAMPLE script 4:

values <- c(10, 20)
result <- exp(mean(log(values)))
result

Comment: If you're asking about geometric means in a vector, why are we working in a [tag:shiny] app? It doesn't matter if a frame/vector is static or changes periodically based on user-interactivity or something else, the math/code is unlikely to change.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and try to make a minimal reproducible example, including desired output.  I agree with @r2evans - drop the shiny code and just try and do it with a data frame.  I would also look at the help file for `help(\`[\`)` to see about subsetting a data frame.

Comment: Also, posting code into comments rarely works as one might hope - it's better to edit your original question and add a code box, then paste into that.

Comment: firuz.safaev, this might be frustrating to you, but I think either PGSA or I can certainly help once the problem is clearer and succinct. Thanks!

Comment: dear r2evans and PGSA, thank you for your remarks. But I would like to check usability of formula by means of reactive() and observe() functions. Therefore, I have to introduce the whole script in the shiny environment.

Comment: I myself  found solution to the question I have asked initially. Hence, the script below is edited and contains the solution to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked about "geometry mean", the general function is

```r
gmean <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  n <- if (na.rm) sum(!is.na(x)) else length(x)
  prod(x, na.rm = na.rm)^(1/n)
}
```

I tweaked the shiny a bit. Some pointers:

- not sure why you had quotes and backticks, not necessary
- `as.numeric(c(0,0))` -> `c(0,0)`, the `0` is already class `numeric`
- `as.data.frame(df1)` -> `df1`, since it's already class `data.frame`
- ignoring `input$recalc`, it's not defined, does/triggers nothing
- `if (!is.null(..))` --> `req(..)`, it handles more situations where you don't want the reactive block to fire, and it does it in a way that can cascade to dependent blocks (`if (!..)` does not and will needlessly cascade)
- it seems odd to predefine `DF2`; as soon as something is edited (or `input$recalc`, whatever that is) in `DF1`, then `DF2` updates

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

gmean <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  n <- if (na.rm) sum(!is.na(x)) else length(x)
  prod(x, na.rm = na.rm)^(1/n)
}

df1 <- data.table(column1 = c(3,8,3,8))
df2 <- data.table(column2 = c(0,0))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Geometric Mean Calculation"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    menuItem("Calculation", tabName = "calculation",
             menuSubItem("Gmean", tabName = "table1"))),
  dashboardBody(
    actionButton("button", label = "Debug!"),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "table1",
        column(
          "table 1",
          width=6,
          rHandsontableOutput("Table1")
        ),
        column(
          "table 2",
          width=6,
          rHandsontableOutput("Table2")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server = function(input, output) {
  data <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    req(input$Table1)
    data$DF1 <- hot_to_r(input$Table1)
  })
  observe({
    req(input$Table2)
    data$DF2 <- hot_to_r(input$Table2)
  })

  observe({
    # input$recalc # ??? no idea
    data$DF1 <- df1
    # data$DF2 <- df2
  })

  output$Table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    req(data$DF1)
    rhandsontable(data$DF1)
  })
  output$Table2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    req(input$Table1, data$DF1)
    data.frame(column2 = c(
      gmean(data$DF1$column1[c(1,3)]),
      gmean(data$DF1$column1[c(2,4)])
    )) |>
      rhandsontable()
  })
  observeEvent(input$button, { browser();1;})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Dear r2evans, thanks for your insightful amendments. Well done. Appreciate!